# Rails 6 I have a select_tag that is not droping down a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-modal

I am re-writing an App called Emissions Gateway from Rails v3.2 to Rails v6.1.4.1

I have about 99% of the app re-written and working but one part is stumping me.
When you go to delete a user it requires that you move any projects they have to a different user.  This normally displays a drop down menu.  The modal is working the buttons are working but the drop down isn't displaying anything and I haven't been able to figure out WHY?

Here is the specific section that has the select_tag:

```
= simple_form_for @user, :html => { :method => :delete } do |f|
                  = select_tag :user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(users_when_being_deleted(@user), "id", "name")
```

Here is the method called users_when_being_deleted in a file called users_helper.rb

```
  def users_when_being_deleted(user = nil)
    if user
      User.where(vendor_id: "current_user.vendor_id").
      and(User.where.not(id: @user.id)).order(:name)
    
    else
      User.where(vendor_id: "current_user.vendor_id").order(:name)
    end
  end
```

Here is a picture of what the modal box looks like when you click on the down arrow:
[image]

Here is the destroy method in the users_controller.rb

```
def destroy
    # check for vendor manager
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @vendor = @user.vendor

    if (@user.id != @vendor.user_manager_id) && params[:user_id].present?
      @user.move_data_to_user(params[:user_id])

      @user.destroy
      flash[:success] = "User removed."
      redirect_to users_url
    else
      redirect_to users_url, notice: "Cannot delete this user."
    end
  end
```

Here is the move_data_to_user method in the model user.rb

```
def move_data_to_user(new_user_id)
    @new_user = User.find_by_id(new_user_id)
    self.articles.each { |a| a.user_id = new_user_id ; a.save }
    self.audits.update_all(user_id: nil)

    self.projects.each do |project|
      Audit.create(class_kind: "project", item_id: project.id, action: "unassigned", new_value: self.name, user_id: User.current_user.id, project_id: project.id)
      Audit.create(class_kind: "project", item_id: project.id, action: "assigned", new_value: @new_user.name, user_id: User.current_user.id, project_id: project.id) unless @new_user.nil?
    end

    self.projects.update_all(user_id: new_user_id, vendor_id: self.vendor_id)
    self.verified_projects.update_all(user_verified_id: new_user_id)
    self.pending_projects.update_all(user_submitted_id: new_user_id)

    @new_user.touch
  end
```

Here is the entire view show.html.haml:

```
- provide(:title, @user.name + " - Profile")
.container-fluid
  #pad-wrapper.user-profile
    // header
    .row-fluid.header
      .span8
        %h3.name{style: "float:none;"}= @user.name
        %span.area #{@user.projects.count} projects
      - if can?(:destroy, @user) && (@user.id != @vendor.user_manager_id)
        = link_to "#", type: "button", id: "user-delete-shortcut", class: "btn btn-danger icon pull-right delete-user", data: { backdrop: "static", toggle: "modal", target: "#user-delete-modal" } do
          %i.icon-trash
        #user-delete-modal.modal.hide.fade{"aria-hidden" => "true", "aria-labelledby" => "user-delete-modal", :role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1"}
          .modal-header.clearfix
            %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} ×
            %h3#UserDeleteModal Delete User
          .modal-body
            .row-fluid
              .span12
                .alert.alert-warning
                  %strong
                    In order to remove this user, you must first reassign their projects to another employee.
            .row-fluid
              .span6.offset3.center
                = simple_form_for @user, :html => { :method => :delete } do |f|
                  = select_tag :user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(users_when_being_deleted(@user), "id", "name")
                  %br/
                  %br/
                  = f.submit "Move Projects & Destroy User", class: 'btn btn-danger center', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure? This cannot be undone!' }

          .modal-footer
            %ul.step_nav
              %li.next
                / = f.submit class: "btn btn-success", name: "Confirm Delete User", value: "Save"
              %li.previous
                %button.btn.btn-danger{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal"} Close

      - if can?(:edit, @user)
        %a.btn.icon.btn-info.pull-right.large.edit{href: edit_user_path(@user)}
          %i.icon-edit
          Edit #{@user.name}



    .row-fluid.profile
      .span9.bio
        .row-fluid
          .span12
            .profile-box
              - if @recent_projects.any?
                .span6
                  %h6 Recent projects
                  %br/
                .span6
                  .span{style: 'padding-right: 10px;'}
                    = will_paginate(@recent_projects, param_name: 'project_page')
                // projects table
                .table-projects{style: "font-size: 15px;"}
                  .row-fluid
                    %table.table.table-hover
                      %thead
                        %tr
                          %th.span3
                            Name
                          %th.span3.hidden-phone
                            %span.line
                            Assessment
                          %th.span3.hidden-phone
                            %span.line
                            Datalogs
                          %th.span3.hidden-phone
                            %span.line
                            Pictures
                          %th.span3
                            %span.line
                            Status
                          %th.span3
                            %span.line
                            Created
                        %tbody
                          - cache ["v1", @recent_projects] do
                            = render @recent_projects
              - else
                %h5.center This user doesn't have any projects yet.
              // Disabled notes, can reenable if use arrises
              / .span12.section.comment
              /   %h6 Add a quick note
              /   %p Add a note about this user to keep a history of your interactions.
              /   %textarea
              /   .span12.submit-box.pull-right
              /     %input.btn-glow.primary{:type => "submit", :value => "Add Note"}/
              /     %span OR
              /     %input.reset{:type => "reset", :value => "Cancel"}/
          .row-fluid
            .profile-box
              .span12
                %h6
                  %i.icon-star
                  Wishes
                %br/
          .row-fluid
            -if @wishes.any?
              %table.table.table-hover
                %thead
                  %tr
                    %th.span12
                      Wish
                    %th.span3
                      %span.line
                      Date
                    %th.span3
                      %span.line
                      Browser
                    %th.span3{colspan: 3}
                      %span.line
                      Status
                %tbody
                  - @wishes.each do |wish|
                    = render "user_wishes", wish: wish
            -else
              .center
                %h4
                  %i.icon-info-sign
                  No wishes have been submitted yet.
                  %br
                  %br
        .row-fluid
          .profile-box
            - if @audits.any?
              .span6
                %h6 Recent Audits
                %br/
              .span6
                .span{style: 'padding-right: 10px;'}
                  = will_paginate(@audits, param_name: 'audit_page')
              // audits table
              .table-audits{style: "font-size: 15px;"}
                .row-fluid
                  %table.table.table-hover
                    %thead
                      %tr
                        %th.span3
                          Timestamp
                        %th.span3.hidden-phone
                          %span.line
                          User
                        %th.span3.hidden-phone
                          %span.line
                          Action
                        %th.span3.hidden-phone
                          %span.line
                          Section
                        %th.span3.hidden-phone
                          %span.line
                          Details
                      %tbody
                        - cache ["v1", @audits] do
                          = render @audits
            - else
              %h5.center This user doesn't have any projects yet.
            // Disabled notes, can reenable if use arrises
            / .span12.section.comment
            /   %h6 Add a quick note
            /   %p Add a note about this user to keep a history of your interactions.
            /   %textarea
            /   .span12.submit-box.pull-right
            /     %input.btn-glow.primary{:type => "submit", :value => "Add Note"}/
            /     %span OR
            /     %input.reset{:type => "reset", :value => "Cancel"}/

      // side column
      .span3.address.pull-right
        .row-fluid
          %h6.center User Details
          #user-more-information.row-fluid.center
            .span6
              %dl
                %dt Vendor
                %dd= @user.vendor.name
                %dt Role
                %dd= @user.role.titleize
                %dt Member Since
                %dd= @user.created_at.strftime("%B #{@user.created_at.day.ordinalize}, %Y")
            .span6
              %dl
                %dt Last Logged In
                %dd= @user.last_sign_in_at ? @user.last_sign_in_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") : "Never"
                %dt Current IP
                %dd= @user.current_sign_in_ip
                %dt Last IP
                %dd= @user.last_sign_in_ip
        .row-fluid.center.section
          %h6 Project Stats
          #user-project-stats
            .span6
              %dl
                %dt Total
                %dd= @user.projects.count
            .span6
              %dl
                %dt Incomplete
                %dd= @user.projects.incomplete.count
                %dt Prepared
                %dd= @user.projects.prepared.count
                %dt Pending
                %dd= @user.projects.pending.count
                %dt Verified
                %dd= @user.projects.verified.count
    .row-fluid
      .span2
        = link_to 'Back', vendor_users_path(@user.vendor_id), class: 'btn'
```

If there is anything anyone else wants to see let me know.  I don't believe there is any separate JavaScript in play beyond the bootstrap modal.  Everything else is pretty much working.  I am getting NO errors in the console about anything, no errors in the Rails console either, its as if once it gets to that modal nothing is happening.  I'm stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank You for your time,
Scott

Comment: In your helper: `User.where(vendor_id: "current_user.vendor_id").` - are you sure this is supposed to be a string there and not `User.where(vendor_id: current_user.vendor_id)` - that would be a really unusal value for the foreign key to have! Same issue in the else clause.

Comment: @BroiSatse  You are the MAN!  I had been working on that all day and I assumed the issue was coming from the front side as other functions that were using that same method were working!  Thank You man I really appreciate it SO much!  I am still pretty new to coding & Ruby on Rails.  This is my second app I am re-writing into the new version of Ruby on Rails, originally that method was written in Squeel code (a gem called squeel which uses it own DSL and its a NIGHTMARE).  I apparently got the translation wrong, Thanks a LOT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the query.

Change

```
User.where(vendor_id: "current_user.vendor_id")
```

To

```
User.where(vendor_id: current_user.vendor_id)
```

Comment: @BroiSatse had originally answered it for me. I was waiting for him to come back and post the answer but he never did..  This WAS in fact the correct answer to the issue I was having.